# Sony SmartWatch 2 Magnetic Fields confusion

Tags: sony

I'm trying to use Registration.SensorTypeValue.MAGNETIC_FIELD in SmartWatch's 2 plugin. But values that I received put me into some dissapointed state, cause of few reason:

1. Values is to big (I tested magnetic fields on 3 phones and result is like "-12. , 38, -14", and the watch give me something like "488, 440, -115")
2. Values are almost static, they live in very small range.

What's wrong with me or with the watch?

I think this question is for Sony support team.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetometer support is currently not functioning correctly in the 1.1.4 version of the SW2 host app.  Unfortunately the plan is to descope this in future releases so the Magnetometer will not be available for apps to use.

Comment: I've owned the watch only few days and all softwares and firmwares are up to date. Maybe you are rigth about defective, I will figure out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, but are the values you're getting supposed to be scaled down or shifted right some few bits before use?   Like a fixed point floating point value.

You say 3 phones give values like "-12, 38, 14", while the watch is giving "488, 440, -115".

Just for fun, consider the watch values in hex (01e8, 01b8, ff8d (32bit signed values))

If we shift each right... 5 bits (divide by 32)... we get:  15, 13, -3.   Which seems more in line with what you expect.

Although perhaps it's 4 bits (div/16), giving: 30, 27, -7.  Probably closer to the proper values there.

Again, this is a guess, I don't have the watch, but many hardware interfaces are like this, raw values are more accurate (or have more digits in their answer).

Sorry about the convert to hex bit, I have trouble shifting bits in decimal, while it's trivial in binary/octal/hex.

Comment: Thanks for good  gues and good info to be knowed. But unfortunately it's not there.